# Поиск одинаковых наибольших строк в K массивах

Tags: массивы, поиск, алгоритм

Приветствую.

Дано K массивов (0 < K < 10) содержащих строки. Необходимо найти наибольшую (по количеству символов) строку, находящуюся во всех K массивах. Не посоветуете алгоритм или код?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Было бы понятно, я бы сюда не писал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение за линию

1. Заводим хеш-мап из строки в битовую маску размера `K`.
2. Для каждой строки заменяем ассоциированную с ней битовую маску на такую же, но с единичкой в разряде, соответсвующем номеру массива.
3. За один проход находим в хеш-мапе строку максимальной длины с битовой маской вида `11111111`.

Псевдо-джава-код:

```
String[][] arrays = ...; //ввод данных
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int k = 0; k < arrays.length; k++) {
    for (String str: arrays[k]) {
        int mask = 1 << k;
        if (map.contains(str)) {
            map.put(str, map.get(str) & mask);
        } else {
            map.put(str, mask);
        }
    }
}

String longest = "";
for (String str : map.getKeys()) {
    if (map.get(str) == (1 << input.length) - 1
            && longest.lenght < str.length) {
        longest = str;
    }
}
System.out.println(longest);
```

Comment: Круто, а можно какой-нибудь пример с кодом? Язык не важен.
Спасибо!

Comment: @Jofsey: а зачем так сложно? Почему не отображать строку на количество массивов?

Comment: @VladD тоже можно, но тогда либо перед увеличением счётчика придётся проверять не встречалась ли эта же строка в этом же массиве ранее, либо для каждой строки проверять её присутствие в каждом из массивов, что уже не за линию.

Comment: @Vlad, одна и та же строка может встречаться в одном массиве несколько раз.

Comment: @VladD щас напишу псевдокод. Если знаете как лаконично избавиться от битовых масок с сохранением асимптотики -- пишите.

Comment: @dzhioev: хм, вы правы.

Comment: @Jofsey: да, и правда, если идти вашим путём, придётся таки заводить маски.

Comment: @Jofsey, только, наверное, вместо

      map.get(str) & mask

надо

       map.get(str) |= mask

Comment: @avp: не, у Java `map.get` [не возвращает lvalue](http://ideone.com/Rh6Qjg). Надо [вот так](http://ideone.com/vLeBhu), длинно.

Answer (score 0):

Если язык не важен, вот вам C#:

```
arrays.First()
      .Where(s => arrays.Skip(1).All(a => a.Contains(s))
      .OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
      .FirstOrDefault()
```

Или так:

```
arrays.Aggregate((intersection, next) => intersection.Intersect(next))
      .OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

(скорость поиска пересечения O(суммарного размера), скорость комбинации `OrderBy` + `First` О(размера пересечения)).

Answer (score 0):

[@andrewshka](/users/2735/andrewshka) с учётом неважности языка, вот пример

```
import Data.List (sortBy, foldl1')
import qualified Data.Set as S
input = [["abracadabra", "good", "fuck"], ["abracadabra", "bad", "fuck"], ["abracadabra", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "fuck", "fuck"]]
out = fst $ head $ sortBy (\(_,x) (_,y) -> compare y x) $ map (\x -> (x, length x)) $ S.toList $ foldl1' S.intersection $ map S.fromList input
main = print out
```

Comment: Хм, а если пересечение пусто, сработает?

Comment: @VladD

    *** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list

Тогда

    case l of {[] -> print "figa"; h:_ -> print h}

Comment: @alexlz: а нету встроенного аналога `FirstOrDefault` с `option`?

Comment: @VladD для head? Не видел

      firstOrDefault l default = case l of {[] -> default; h:_ -> h}

Так? Теперь есть :)

Comment: @alexlz: скорее

    maybeFirst l = case l of {[] -> Nothing; h:_ -> Just h}

(если я не напутал с синтаксисом)

Comment: И так, и так. Это разные функции разных типов.

      firstOrDefault :: [t] -> t -> t
      maybeFirst :: [a] -> Maybe a

Но в Вашем случае никакими default'ами не пахнет.

Comment: Ну, решение с `maybeFirst` мне показалось больше в духе ФП.

Comment: @alexlz, а это что за язык? Какой-нибудь Хаскель?

Comment: @avp: он самый.

Comment: @VladD

     out = (\s -> if S.null s then "Нет таких" else fst $ head $ sortBy (\(_,x) (_,y) -> compare y x) $ map (\x -> (x, length x)) $ S.toList s) $ foldl1' S.intersection $ map S.fromList input
     main = putStrLn out

А если сильно нравятся монады Maybe, то

     out = Just input >>= Just . map S.fromList >>= Just . foldl1' S.intersection >>= (\x -> if S.null x then Nothing else Just x) >>= Just . S.toList >>= Just . map (\x -> (x, length x)) >>= Just . sortBy (\(_,x) (_,y) -> compare y x) >>= Just . fst . head 
     main = putStrLn $ case out of {Nothing -> "Нет таких"; Just x -> x}